# Equivalent for "qt" R function in Python

Tags: python, r, scipy, statistics, probability

I have the following code in R:

```
n <- 112 # Observations 
p <- 4 # Variables
alpha <- 0.05 # Alpha is alpha 
quant = qt(1-alpha/2, n-p-1) # which is 1.982383
```

From my research, the `qt` function from R is related with to the *t*-distribution: [R - qt function syntax](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/TDist.html)

My question is:

> How can I get the equivalent in Python?

Comment: The passing of variables is trivial, so I assume you're asking for a `qt()` function equivalent in python, in which case Stack Overflow may not be the right website for this (im not entirely certain). However, the most equivalent function in python i could find is in the module `numpy`. Import numpy into your python script and use `numpy.quantile()`

Comment: you might want to checkout `numpy` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.standard_t.html or `Scipy` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html library

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python quantile function", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is `scipy.stats.t.ppf`:

```
In [26]: import scipy.stats                                                                              
In [27]: n = 112                                                                                         
In [28]: p = 4                                                                                           
In [29]: alpha = 0.05                                                                                    
In [40]: scipy.stats.t.ppf(1 - alpha / 2, n - p - 1)                                                              
Out[40]: 1.9823833701230174
```

Alternatively, if you'd rather get rid of manually specifying that the tail is what you're interested in, there's `scipy.stats.t.isf`:

```py
In [40]: scipy.stats.t.isf(alpha / 2, n - p - 1)                                                              
Out[40]: 1.9823833701230174
```

Comment: More info here : http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/en_Tanagra_Calcul_P_Value.pdf